# jquery .html() doesn't preserve input values

Tags: jquery

I have a button on my web page that, when clicked, does the following:

1. Gets the contents of a "template table" by calling .html() on that table
2. Stores the contents of the above call in a variable
3. Does a global replace on that variable to track table row number
4. Replaced contents are added to my "real table"

Problem: Values entered by users into input fields in those table rows are not preserved. Here's the code:

```
function addRowToCluesTable() {
    var t = $("#template").html().replace(/{NUM}/g, stepCount);
    var r = $("#real").html();
    $("#real").html(r + "\n\n" + t);
}
```

This all works fine EXCEPT that any input fields in the "real" table (non-template) containing values entered by users are lost and all values are returned to their default or empty state. So the flow goes like this: row is added, values entered into real table, another row added, values entered...repeat.

How can I get jquery to preserve the user-supplied input values when dynamically adding rows? Instead of storing real table contents in a variable should I instead append template rows to the end of the real table? If so, what's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try appending the new html instead:

```
$('#real').append(t);
```